# Custom Bottom Navigation library round selector

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view, bottomnavigationview

I found those two library but they are for flutter, are those similar library for Android native.
Or how can I replicate this behavior, animate the bottom nav bar.
The first library is: ff_navigation_bar

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?

Comment: Found a hack tho

Comment: @Dr4ke the b4dass can you post your hack?

Comment: in flutter https://github.com/hacktons/convex_bottom_bar

Answer (score 1):

https://androidexample365.com/a-simple-curved-material-navigation-bottom/

`MeowBottomNavigation` is the library name. (In case if the link is broken)

[Here is the custom method if you don't want to use library](https://medium.com/@androidtutorial/draw-custom-shapes-in-curved-bottom-navigation-view-361c9a5507dd)

[Morph navigation library](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/morph-bottom-navigation)

[Space-Navigation-View](https://github.com/irfaan008/IRBottomNavigationView)

They are the similar libraries that you want :)

Otherwise, if you want the more precise things. Custom View will rescue you

Comment: I've seen this, but they are different, meowBottomNavigation leave a space around the icon, while What I want, add a space, sorta wrap it.

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass updated answer. You can use the custom method!

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass you can modify the custom method according to your own requirements. :)

Comment: Thanks I will try, but I need a more precise solution please.

Comment: @Dr4ketheb4dass https://github.com/irfaan008/IRBottomNavigationView
does this help?

Comment: Sorry no, because there''s no transition when you click other icon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208581/discussion-between-dr4ke-the-b4dass-and-muhammad-saad).