# Custom Bottom Navigation Rounded across icon

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

Cannot find the solution to draw such a bottom navigation. This question was already asked more than 3 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399298/custom-bottom-navigation-library-round-selector).

I tried to edit code from provided links there, but not successful. Maybe somebody has a solution already or can point me out to specific library?
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLVIB.gif)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.